# Firefox keyboard conflict: Command key, Control key, and Contextual Menus

Tags: keyboard, firefox, shortcut-menu, web-app

I am using OSX 10.8, Firefox 17, and ruTorrent, a front-end webapp that displays a list of files on a server.

Clicking on files while holding down the command key only highlights the newly clicked file. Discontiguous file selection is not possible.

Clicking on files while holding down the control key results in two sets of contextual menus (shortcut menus) appearing one atop the other: Firefox's shortcut menu (in System font) and ruTorrent's shortcut menu (in smaller Web app font, beneath). One click of the mouse dismisses the Firefox menu.

I would like to know (1) how to get the command key and the control key to work normally within the ruTorrent webapp or, at the very least, (2) how to disable shortcut menus on the Firefox layer.

Answer (score 1):

The contextual menu problem was resolved when I updated my version of Firefox from 17 (December 2012) to 23(!) in September 2013. The built-in update button within Firefox updated my app to 17.0.2esr (security updates) and offered no info about the later versions.

Only after searching other Firefox questions here did I notice someone mentioning version 20 and up. I do not know why Firefox 17 did not issue an alert or a chance to upgrade itself to a higher version, or if it did, why I had not noticed that as it climbed from version 17 to 23.

The noncontiguous selection problem (clicking while holding the command key) still remains, but I suspect it is a problem with PHP5.0, the language the Web app is programmed in, or a bug within the app's code.